# With the Start Date and End Date given , finding date counts in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the pandas df in the following format (with NoOFDays being EndDate - StartDate)

```
------------------------------------------
|Item | StartDate | EndDate    | NoOFDays|
------------------------------------------
| A |  01-Jan-2018| 04-Jan-2018|    4    |
| A |  07-Jan-2018| 08-Jan-2018|    2    |
| B |  03-Jan-2018| 05-Jan-2018|    3    |
| A |  03-Jan-2018| 05-Jan-2018|    3    |
------------------------------------------
```

And wanted to get the count of each day grouped by item

```
A 01-Jan-2018 1
A 02-Jan-2018 1
A 03-Jan-2018 2
A 04-Jan-2018 2
A 05-Jan-2018 1
A 06-Jan-2018 0
A 07-Jan-2018 1
A 08-Jan-2018 1
B 01-Jan-2018 0
B 02-Jan-2018 0
B 03-Jan-2018 1
B 04-Jan-2018 1
B 05-Jan-2018 1
B 06-Jan-2018 0
B 07-Jan-2018 0
B 08-Jan-2018 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this. It is a bit ugly, as I couldn't manage to get a solution without iterating through one of the dataframes. It could be done by iterating over the original data, or the new df with the list of all dates.

I had a similar problem, any cleaner ways of doing this would be appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Item':['A','A','B','A'], 
                        'StartDate':['2018-01-01','2018-01-07', '2018-01-03','2018-01-03'],
                        'EndDate': ['2018-01-04','2018-01-08','2018-01-05','2018-01-05']})
df['StartDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['StartDate'])
df['EndDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['EndDate'])


index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A','B'],pd.date_range(start = df.StartDate.min(), end = df.EndDate.max())], names=['item', 'date'])
new_df = pd.DataFrame(index = index, data = {'counts':0})

dates_list = new_df.index.get_level_values(1)
items_list = new_df.index.get_level_values(0)
for row in df.itertuples():
  new_df.counts[(items_list == row.Item) & (dates_list>=row.StartDate) & (dates_list<= row.EndDate)] += 1

print(new_df)
```

Which gives this. You can remove the multi-index later if needed

```
                 counts
item date              
A    2018-01-01       1
     2018-01-02       1
     2018-01-03       2
     2018-01-04       2
     2018-01-05       1
     2018-01-06       0
     2018-01-07       1
     2018-01-08       1
B    2018-01-01       0
     2018-01-02       0
     2018-01-03       1
     2018-01-04       1
     2018-01-05       1
     2018-01-06       0
     2018-01-07       0
     2018-01-08       0
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is groupby with multiple columns.
Based on this example your pandas groupby would look like this :

`df.groupby(['Item', 'StartDate']).agg(['count'])`

Comment: But Nischal , the dataset over here isn't straight forward to apply groupby. Meaning , the first row has the following implicit dates - 01 Jan , 02 Jan , 03 Jan , 04 Jan) second record has the dates - 07 Jan , 08-Jan and so on... I understand I need to use date functionality to get all the dates in each row and then group it. But unsure of how to do this using pandas utilities.

Comment: @Maddy Can you add the sample exactly how your dataset is like, then we can help..

Comment: Try this df.gropuby('date col').datecol.count()